# Floating Integer Array Java Code

Tags: java, arrays

The full assignment is: Take 10 floating point numbers as inputs, and displays the average of the numbers followed by all of the numbers that are greater than the average. I was able to get the average quite easily, but when I cant get it to print out the numbers greater than the average. I had tried something earlier, but changed it since it just printed out a memory location and not the actual number. Any help is appreciated.

If this is unclear in my previously stated question: Currently my code outputs the average of the numbers as the user is inputting them and compares this to the new number. What I would like to do is compare all of the numbers entered to the final average of all 10 numbers. I was not so sure how to do this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayProgram2
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double [] numberList = new double[10];
        double [] largerList = new double [10];
        int largerCounter = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter any number");
            double data = scan.nextDouble();
            numberList[i] = data;
            sum += numberList[i];
            double average = sum/numberList.length;

            if(data > average){
                largerList[largerCounter] = data;
                largerCounter++;
            }

        }
        for(int i = 0; i <largerCounter; i++){
            System.out.println("The numbers greater than the average are " + " " + largerList[i]);
        }
        double average = sum/numberList.length;
        System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + average);
    }//main

}//class
```

Comment: Your loop seems to keep track of the elements that are larger than the _current_ average.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I wanted it to keep track of all of the numbers and then compare these numbers to the final average. This is what was unclear to me. Should I use a second for loop outside of this one to keep track of this? Or declare the average as final?

Comment: @Smith You will need a second `for` loop.  Mathematically, you _cannot_ tell what numbers are larger than the average until you compute the average.  So you need to wait until the average is computed, then perform another loop.  The `final` keyword in Java has absolutely nothing to do with this being the "final average", so don't even think about using it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayProgram2
{ 
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double [] numberList = new double[10];
    double [] largerList = new double [10];
    int largerCounter = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.print("Please enter any number: ");
        numberList[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        sum += numberList[i];
    }    
    double average = sum/numberList.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(numberList[i] > average){
            largerList[largerCounter] = numberList[i];
            largerCounter++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <largerCounter; i++){
        System.out.println("The numbers greater than the average are " + " " + largerList[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + average);    
}//main
}//class
```

Comment: Even if this helped the OP, you don't do anything to explain why it's correct, or what was even wrong with the original code.

Comment: Already in the comments mentioned what are the mistakes. Sorry but my English is not very good.

Comment: I don't see any comments on this answer.  Again, this isn't to be too harsh, but think of answers as their own individual entities related to the question.  A clear answer shouldn't rely on inference or context from comments (which may be deleted later).

Answer (score 0):

Your code will get the final average at the end of the loop (all 10 elements will be summed, and then divided by 10).  A second loop through the input double to compare them the final average is what you need.

```
    for(int i = 0; i <numberList; i++){
        if (numberList[i] > average) {
            largerList[largerCounter] = data;
            largerCounter++;
        }
    }
```

should go immediately after getting all the inputs (your first for loop)

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the just sum before you bother calculating the average, at the moment you're calculating the average of the the first number, then the first 2 numbers, then the first 3 etc. The first `double average = sum/numberList.length;` isn't needed unless (as the first comment states) you want to compare the current number to the current average:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter any number");
    double data = scan.nextDouble();
    numberList[i] = data;
    sum += numberList[i];

    /*Not needed
    double average = sum/numberList.length;

    if(data > average){
        largerList[largerCounter] = data;
        largerCounter++;
    */
    }

}
```

If you want to check which numbers are greater than the *overall* average, change

```
for(int i = 0; i <largerCounter; i++){
        System.out.println("The numbers greater than the average are " + " " + largerList[i]);
}
double average = sum/numberList.length;
System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + average);
```

to something like:

```
double average = sum/numberList.length; //now needs to be calculated first
System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + average);

System.out.println("The numbers greater than the average are") //display this once

for(int i = 0; i <largerCounter; i++){
    if (numberList[i] > average)
        System.out.println(" " + largerList[i]); //no need for a list to store the values greater than average, just print them if they meet the criteria.
}
```